# Test for difference by outcome (Yes/No) by each level of a factor - with one outcome level missing in a factor level

Tags: r, testing, anova, kruskal-wallis

I need a method to divide a vector (bloodsample values) by each level of a factor of time intervals (gacat) and compare these data (by t.test/ANOVA or Kruskal Wallis) between two levels in an outcome factor variable (EPL (yes/no))

In the mtcars df:

```
df1 <- mtcars
df1$cyl  <- factor(df1$cyl)
df1$gear <- factor(df1$gear)
```

This code solves my problem nicely., using anova:

```
lapply(split(df1, df1$gear), function(d){summary(aov(mpg~cyl, data=d))})
```

However, as the last level of my data in `split` (in the above example gear) only has *one* of the yes/no outcome, the entire code throws the error:

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
 contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

My data:

```
             No Yes
<6 weeks     89  21
6-8 weeks   166  37
8-10 weeks  158  18
10-12 weeks 131   5
>12 weeks    90   **0**
```

It is the zero in * that seems to be the problem...
In the example, this is not a problem as every factor has at least two levels:

```
table(df1$cyl, df1$gear)
    3  4  5
 4  1  8  2
 6  2  4  1
 8 12  0  2
```

As I need to examine a lot of blood samples, I would love a way to do these comparisons by a short code-block. Any way to make R throw a NaN for the last level, in stead of dropping the entire code?